# Unable to enable Slack's "Enable Events" through Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, post, google-apps-script, slack-api

So I'm attempting to create a SlackBot which can track reacts to a message it posted. However, I'm also trying to read from a Google Sheet, so the code for the bot will be in a Google Script connecting to the form.

I clearly need to enable events in order to see reacts, and the first step is to receive and respond to a POST request Slack sends:

```
Our Request:
POST
"body": { 
     "type": "url_verification",
     "token": "---",
     "challenge": "---"
}
```

I have to respond with something along the lines of:

```
HTTP 200 OK, 
Content-type: text/plain, 
"the challenge code"
```

When I recieve the POST request, it overwrites square 1,1 of the Google Sheet, which is not great, but more concerningly, my doPost function doesn't run.

Here's what I get back from Slack:

```
Your Response:
"code": 200
"error": "challenge_failed"
"body": {
 <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Error</title><style type="text/css">body {background-color: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0;}.errorMessage {font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 25px;}</style></head><body style="margin:20px"><div><img alt="Google Apps Script" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/logo.png"></div><div style="text-align:center;font-family:monospace;margin:50px auto 0;max-width:600px">The script completed but did not return anything.</div></body></html> 
}
```

Now, here's all the code I have in my Google Script.

```js
function doPost(request){

  var postJSON = request.postData.getDataAsString();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  // doesn't happen
  sheet.getRange(5, 3).setValue("YEAH");
  // when I send a req using CURL, I get the message
  // "The script completed but did not return anything"
  return postJSON;
}
```

It's already deployed as a web app, and I've been updating it every time I make a change to the code, so that isn't the issue.

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think that in this case, it is required to return the value of `challenge`. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var postJSON = request.postData.getDataAsString();
```

#### To:

```
var postJSON = JSON.parse(request.postData.getDataAsString());
```

And also, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
return postJSON;
```

#### To:

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput(postJSON.challenge);
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that `postJSON` in your current script is `{"type": "url_verification", "token": "---", "challenge": "---"}`. Please be careful this.
- Also, it supposes that the Web Apps is deployed as `Execute the app as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone, even anonymous`.
- **When the script of Web Apps is modified, please redeploy it as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

#### References:

- [Subscribing to event types](https://api.slack.com/events-api#subscriptions)
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Class ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service)